# Data Validation in mvvm

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, mvvm-light, idataerrorinfo

I have a application with multiply  ViewModels. Some property have DataAnnotations.

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is required.")]
    [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is out of range.")]
    public int Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_password != value)
            {
                _password = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
    }
```

How validation can be done by implementing the IDataErrorInfo or INotifyDataErrorInfo interface for all viewmodels?

I use [This](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/02/22/validating-our-viewmodel) article, but validate when propertychange and don't validate required field.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example which uses `IDataErrorInfo`. This should help you get started.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LeftErrorTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent, ElementName=ErrorAdorner}" Background="Red" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,66,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="44" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,65,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
             Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource LeftErrorTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = new ViewModel();

            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : ObservableBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                string errorMessage = string.Empty;

                switch (columnName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                            errorMessage = "Enter name";
                        else if (Name.Trim() == string.Empty)
                            errorMessage = "Enter valid name";
                        break;
                }
                return errorMessage;
            }
        }

    }

    public class ObservableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want created a validation class for all application and all ViewModel inherit of validation class.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you will have to create some method that Validates the annotations Like ValidateMethod in my code

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged,IDataErrorInfo
    {
        int _password;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is required.")]
        [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Field 'Range' is out of range.")]
        public int Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_password != value)
                {
                    _password = value;
                    Validate("Password", value);
                    Notify("Password");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Validate(string propertyName, object value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

            string error = string.Empty;

            var results = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>(2);

            bool result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                value,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                {
                    MemberName = propertyName
                },
                results);

            if (!result && (value == null || ((value is int || value is long) && (int)value == 0) || (value is decimal && (decimal)value == 0)))
                return;

            if (!result)
            {
                System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult validationResult = results.First();
                if (!errorMessages.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                    errorMessages.Add(propertyName, validationResult.ErrorMessage);
            }

            else if (errorMessages.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                errorMessages.Remove(propertyName);
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged 

        public void Notify(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        #region IDataErrorInfo

        public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> errorMessages = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get 
            { 
                if(errorMessages.ContainsKey(columnName))
                    return errorMessages[columnName];
                return null;

            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**>xaml**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Password, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="70" Width="200" />
```

> xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

You need to call the Validate method from setter of the property which applies DataAnnotations and make sure call it before Notifying the PropertyChanged.

Comment: Thanks, but the PropertyChanged don't  notifying in required validation, and i should call the validation method for all required property in submit button.

Comment: Yes You will have to call that for all the Properties that you want to vaildate and what you mean by PropertyChanged don't notifying in required validation

Comment: the validations are only fired when the binding happens. What happens when the user starts up the screen and clicks on the submit button directly...No binding happens and hence no validation is fired..

Comment: you can see there is dictionary (errorMessages ) that has error Messages you can use that If the Count of Dictionary is greater than 1 you keep your button Disabled and if you want to Notify then just RaisePropertyChanged for each Property in the Key of Dictionary.

Comment: See that depends upon your Logic How you doing it . For this You need to bind the Command for Button. And I dont have code for that now as am not on my Laptop.